# Getting a TB test to stay in UK

Tags: uk, health

I'm looking to apply for a parental visa for the UK but I came over from South Africa without doing the TB x-ray back home. I need the TB test as per the gov website: **your tuberculosis test results if you’re from a country where you have to take the test**.

Does this mean I need the x-rays or can I just do the blood test and get the certificate?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are applying for a Parent of a Tier 4 Child visa, you need a chest x-ray https://www.gov.uk/tb-test-visa
There’s an approved clinic in Wimpole Street, London https://london-imaging.co.uk/service/visa-x-ray/

Comment: @Mark Vincer, There’s a clinic in London, I’ve updated my answer. I’d imagine there may be others in the larger cities outside London.